# Can I check the integrity of an entire website?

Tags: security, browser, hash

I was wondering if there's a way to check the integrity of a webpage and all it's resources (scripts, images, styles). I imagine that the browser could generate a hash value of a website and all it's resources to check if something about the website has changed.

Can any modern browsers do this? If not, is there and app or extension that automatically does it?

Or is there another, better way of checking if something about a website has changed?

Comment: How about an ETag? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Comment: The *integrity* is guaranteed by HTTPS. If you want to detect when it changes, that's something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a tool to audit your code, right?

If that's what you're talking about, then try [Bolt](https://bolt.whitesourcesoftware.com/). It is a free tool that can be linked to your repository (Github), which automatically audits the code every time you commit.

This tool scans the code and looks for vulnerabilities in the [National Vulnerability Database](https://nvd.nist.gov/).

If it finds any known vulnerabilities, then it will create an issue on your repository.

[image]

I know that is fairly simple to use, but if you want you can write the configuration for it in a predefied file named `.whitesource`, that you place in the root of your repository.

```
{
  "checkRunSettings": {
    "vulnerableCheckRunConclusionLevel": "failure"
  },
  "issueSettings": {
    "minSeverityLevel": "LOW"
  }
}
```